# Scraping data with Python LXML XPath

Tags: python, html-parsing, lxml

I am trying to parse a website for

```
blahblahblah 
<a  href="THIS IS WHAT I WANT" title="NOT THIS">I DONT CARE ABOUT THIS EITHER</a>
blahblahblah
```

(there are many of these, and I want all of them in some tokenized form). The problem is that "a  href" actually has two spaces, not just one (there are some that are "a href" with one space that I do NOT want to retrieve), so using tree.xpath('//a/@href') doesn't quite work. Does anyone have any suggestions on what to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works as expected :

```
from lxml import etree

file = "file:///path/to/file.html" # can be a http URL too
doc = etree.parse(file)

print doc.xpath('//a/@href')[0]
```

Edit : it's not possible AFAIK to do what you want with `lxml`.

You can use a [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) instead.

Comment: Hi, this works to extract "a href" with one space, but it is not working to extract "a href" where there are two spaces between a and href. I only want the links where there are two spaces between a and href.

Comment: No, like tdelaney said, XML + Xpath don't care about spaces. My script treat both cases, just remove `[0]` (first element) and add another links, they all will be displayed. (but sounds not reliable more than 1 day)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about LXML, but you can definitely use BeautifulSoup, find all `<a>` on the page, and than create a for loop, where you will check if `<a  href=...>` matches your regex pattern, if it match, than scrap url.

Answer (score 0):

"(there are some that are "a href" with one space that I do NOT want to retrieve)"

I think this means that you only want to locate elements where there is more than one space between the a and the href. XML allows any amount of whitespace between tag name and attribute (spaces, tabs, new lines are all allowed). The whitespace is discarded by the time the text is parsed and the document tree is created. LXML and XPATH are working with Node objects in the Document tree, not the original text that was parsed to make the tree.

One option is to use regular expressions to find the text you want. But really, since this is perfectly valid XML/HTML, why bother to remove a few spaces?

Comment: The site I'm scraping has certain links that are "a ref" with one space, and "a  ref" with two spaces. I only want the links that have two spaces. Using sputnik's code only retrieves the links with one space, NOT the links with two spaces (if it retrieved both, I could do some more parsing on my end, but this is not the case!)

Comment: Okay, you could read the page, replace('a  href', 'a spaceyref'), load the xml and use xpath to find spaceyref.

Answer (score 0):

Use an xpath expression to find all the  nodes, then iterate through all those nodes looking for a match, you can obtain a string representation of the node with :

```
etree.tostring(node)
```

For futher reference : http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#elements-carry-attributes-as-a-dict